# Not able to write to app specific directory in Android SD card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I learnt that from KitKat an application can only write to its specific directory.

But strangely i am not able to write into my specific application directory also.

Code to get the sd card directory

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command("mount").start();
    process.waitFor();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // Output the line of output from the mount command
        logger.debug("   {}", line);

        if (line.startsWith("/dev/block/vold/")) {
            String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
            if (tokens.length >= 3 && (tokens[2].equals("vfat") || tokens[2].equals("exfat"))) {
                String path = tokens[1];
                File file = new File(path);
                if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {
                    logger.debug("Detected SD card at {}", file.getPath());

                    if (!file.canWrite()) {
                        logger.warn("The SD card path {} is reporting that it is not writable", file.getPath());
                    }
                    // path = basecontext.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath();

                    return path;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Code to get a file

Here is how i construct the file path :
sdCardDirectory is the directory which i get like this: `/storage/extSdCard/`
directory and sub directory are my application sepcifc subdirectoryies but are obviously inside the app specific directory in the application

```
sdCardDirectory + File.separator + "Android" + File.separator + "data" + File.separator
                    + <my app package> + File.separator + subdirectory
                    + File.separator + directory+ File.separator + document.getRepositoryId() + FILENAME_SEPARATOR
                + fetchObjectId(document);
```

Where the ids retrieved are simple alpha numeric strings for e.g. aBc45ef_0

```
randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
```

I am getting

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/myapp/cache/downloaded/OhCQL_RQl8IJcVlO5T1MX4-3SQg_mMDT5PWtf-IYmE0: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

Where myapp is the my application package name.

**UPDATE** This is the link to Android bug which i have opened https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69549&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

cheers,
Saurav

Comment: Please post some code with your whole proper logcat error .

Comment: Have you added the permission to `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL _STORAGE` in your manifest?

Comment: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is added and i think READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE gets added implicitly

Comment: You did not tell what was returned as path. Moreover you don't show how you initiated variable file. In this way we cannot check the path mentioned in the file not found exception.

Comment: @greenapps path returned is /storage/extSdCard/. So path is correctly returned

Comment: We still cannot check your error as you don't show how you initialise File file.

Comment: @greenapps would that matter? because if you see my code of finding the sd card directory..the directory is never writable..log logger.warn("The SD card path {} is reporting that it is not writable", file.getPath()); is printed always

Comment: Yes that would matter. As the SD card can be unwritable but your app directory on it not.

Comment: @greenapps yes got your point... i have updated the original post with the code to fetch the path with which i create the file instance

Comment: We still cannot check "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/myapp/cache/downloaded/OhCQL_RQl8IJcVlO5T1MX4-3SQg_mMDT5PWtf-IYmE0: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)" as we do not need to see the code how you construct the filepath but only want to see which filepath you try. And code where we can see that all directories exist of that path. And if not that you are going to create them. You could also mention if the path exists having looked with a filemanager.

Answer (score 0):

> But strangely i am not able to write into my specific application directory also.

That code is not necessarily going to give you anything that you can use. Please use `getExternalFilesDirs()` (note the plural); the second and subsequent entries in the returned list will be from removable storage, where available.

You may wish to read [my blog post on Android 4.4 and removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) for more background.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the response. But this method is from API level 19.I am getting the read only error in API level 17 also.

Comment: @saurav: "But this method is from API level 19" -- correct. There is `ContextCompat` and its version of the method, though that will still only return paths on removable media on API Level 19+ devices. It merely allows you to avoid the `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` checks yourself. "I am getting the read only error in API level 17 also" -- your existing code is not going to be reliable across OS versions or devices. Removable media is not part of the Android SDK prior to API Level 19. This is covered in the blog post that I linked to in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Mark again for the response. getExternalFilesDirs() returning me  the internal emulated storage /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myapp/files in API Level 17.Is API level 17 also has the same write restriction on SD card ?

Comment: @saurav: The behavior of removable storage prior to API Level 19 is up to the device manufacturer.

Comment: On my 4.4.2 device getExternalFilesDirs() has only one item. (The same as mentioned by saurav). It does not mention the removable storage. Moreover apps cannot write to the micro SD card. Not even to their own Android/data/package/files directory as that directory is not there and cannot be created. What is 'funny' is that apps can write everywhere in the internal /sdcard.

Comment: @greenapps: "On my 4.4.2 device getExternalFilesDirs() has only one item. It does not mention the removable storage" -- that too is the device manufacturer's choice. In particular, I would expect to see that behavior more likely on devices that were upgraded to 4.4.x, with devices that ship with 4.4+ offering better removable media support.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but on API 19. I'm using getExternalFilesDirs() to retrieve the removable files. I test the path with File.canWrite() method to make sure it's not in readonly, but when I try to write a file into that folder I get a FileNotFoundException: open failed: EROFS (Read Only FileSystem)... How is it possible ? Lots of my users are having this issue (but not all)

Comment: @greenapps i am getting the same behaviour...what is confusing for me is even 4.1, 4.2 and 4.4 based devices are having the same problem. Probably i have to test on another sd card also

Comment: Connecting the device with usb cable to pc the pc can write on the card with the MTP protocol. Or better: Android OS writes on the card. But apps can not.

Comment: On my 4.4.2 device getExternalFilesDirs() only shows one item, but I have write access to the removable SD card through the path /storage/sdcard1, which does not require root permission.

Comment: @CarlosHoyos: My guess is that your device shipped with an earlier version of Android (e.g., 4.3 or 4.2), and the manufacturer did not change this aspect of the device configuration when you were upgraded. Either that, or your device did not ship with the Play Store (at least, not legitimately).